# Collecting Transformers and Anime figures haram?

Tags: halal-haram, sunni

I used to collect Transformers figures (not posters, just figures) since 2007 till 2010. Now, I want to return back to collecting them when I have rented a new house (Insha'Allah), when attending the uni next year (Insha'Allah). Also, I want to collect Japanese toys as well (such examples are plushies and/or figma of Hatsune Miku or plushies and/or nendoroid of "Himouto! Umaru-Chan"). Would it be classified under buying statues? I am looking for a Sunni point of view.